# How to Swap Coordinates of jts.geom.Geometry object from Lat, Long to Long,Lat in JTS

Tags: java, geotools, jts

I have a geometry object of type (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry). it is currently in latitude, longitude form and I'd like to flip the coordinates so that its longitude latitude so that I can have it in GeoJSON format for mongodb.

My constraints that I am seeing are:
a) the input that I would like to flip coordinates for is a Geometry object.
b) The Geometry object will be either a Polygon type or Multipolygon.
c) I would like to flip the coordinates before the type cast to Polygon/multipolygon

I have tried geo.reverse() but it does not work.

As well, I have tried using:
CRSAuthorityFactory   factory = CRS.getAuthorityFactory(true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326");

And another option and I did not see it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution to this is extending the class to provide an additional function that either outputs the data you need in some convenient way:

```
public Coordinate[] getReversedCoordinates(){

  Coordinate[] original = this.getCoordinates();
  Coordinate[] ret = new Coordinate[original.length];

  for(int i =0; i<original.length; i++){
      ret[i] = new Coordinate( original[i].x , original[i].y );
  }

  return ret;

}
```

Alternately you could alter the interpretation of the data. It's a little harder for me to give you a code snippet for that as I'm not sure how you're using the information specifically.

EDIT:

Once you have the reversed coordinates,you can create a duplicate Geometry of type linear ring. A means of doing this is to use your factory to use your geometry factory:

```
GeometryFactory gf = //However this was instantiated;
Coordinate[] reversedCoordinates = getReversedCoordinates();
gf.createLinearRing(reversedCoordinates);
```

Happy coding and leave a comment if you have any questions!

Comment: hi! I tried the above code and have a further question, do you think this will work for the Polygon and Multipolygon shapes? It seems that GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory() and then gf.toGeometry(...) does not have an input for the Coordinate[] value returned by the proposed method.

Comment: Can you clarify how it is that your program will be interacting with GeoJSON? Does it just pass a polygon object? If so, you may want to just create a duplicate polygon with the coordinates reversed.

Comment: Yes a duplicate polygon with coordinates reversed would be great, but I am unable to create this duplicate polygon. I am starting out with a WKT, parsing it as a Geometry and then converting to geojson successfully, except the coordinates are not in the correct order, geojson needs to be long,lat for mongodb

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think is a potential solution. Let me know how that works

Comment: sure thing! Let us know if it worked and if it did, can you hi the green check next to my answer? ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can use a CoordinateFilter to invert all x and y values in a given geometry.

```
private static class InvertCoordinateFilter implements CoordinateFilter {
    public void filter(Coordinate coord) {
        double oldX = coord.x;
        coord.x = coord.y;
        coord.y = oldX;
    }
}
```

Then apply the filter thusly:

```
// Invert Coordinates since GeoJSON likes them that way
myGeometryObj.apply(new InvertCoordinateFilter());
```

Comment: Excellent and elegant solution! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great solution, although as the [javadoc](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateFilter.html) say, there is no guarantee that coordinates will be modified: the `CoordinateFilter` is usualyl meant for other purposes. They suggest to use the [**`CoordinateSequenceFilter`**](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateSequenceFilter.html)for changes on coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is that the Geometry.getCoordinates() gives a Coordinate[] array which is live.
Therefore, I could use the following:

Where myGeometryObject is a Geometry object:

```
Coordinate[] original = myGeometryobject.getCoordinates();
for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
    Double swapValue = original[i].x;
    original[i].x = original[i].y;
    original[i].y = swapValue;
}
```

The changes to the Coordinate objects will affect the underlying Geometry permanently.

Answer (score 2):

As important addendum to the existing answers: You should always call yourGeometry.geometryChanged() after you changed a Geometry's geometry!

See http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#getCoordinates%28%29 and http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#geometryChanged%28%29

Comment: Good point, but by using the [_CoordinateSequenceFilter_](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateSequenceFilter.html) the `geometryChanged()` methods gets automatically called as soon as you declare that you have changed the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

As the JTS [javadocs](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateFilter.html) suggest, it is best to use a [**`CoordinateSequenceFilter`**](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateSequenceFilter.html) to change the coordinates of a geometry in place.

```
/**
 * Swaps the XY coordinates of a geometry.
 */
public void swapCoordinates(Geometry g) {
    g.apply(new CoordinateSequenceFilter() {

        @Override
        public void filter(CoordinateSequence seq, int i) {
            double oldX = seq.getCoordinate(i).x;
            seq.getCoordinate(i).x = seq.getCoordinate(i).y;
            seq.getCoordinate(i).y = oldX;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isGeometryChanged() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

---

<sub>NOTE: there are nasty cases where `Coordinate` object you get access to is a *copy* of what is internally stored (eg. see [`PackedCoordinateSequence`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/impl/PackedCoordinateSequence.html)). In that case, as suggested in the javadocs, you must use the provided setters, that is *setX()* *setY()*.</sub>

---

<sub>There are also even nastier cases where there is simply no way to change the coordinates in place, eg. when fetching a geometry from the DB with PostGIS where this Geolatte [`PackedPositionSequence`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=geolatte-geom-master/src/main/java/org/geolatte/geom/PackedPositionSequence.java) sequence implementation just won't let you modify the coordinates (afaik).</sub>

Comment: Thank to your answer I've managed that that for all geom types I've done transformation by setting new values using seq.setOrdinate(i, 0, _newXValue_); and same for y but using ordinate index 1

Comment: Thanks @MarkoDjurovic, yes that is a correct way for sure. Still a `PackedPositionSequence` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on _setOrdinate()_: it's just unmutable I believe. I solved it by just making my own new geometry out of such unmutable coordinates, then work on it.