# Change the axis of lat long when using JTS jackson

Tags: jackson, jts

I am using locationtech JTS library in spring boot with jackson as json serializer and a Jts-data-type module with supports serializing JTS geometry.The issue which i am facing is the axis order of coordinates when json is returned is long lat instead of lat long there is a solution on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634389/1574921 i want to know if there is any other way to achieve this functionality instead of always applying InvertCoordinateFilter whenever i create a functionality.
Below is the code which i am using

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JtsModule());


    double lat  = 32.3456789;
    double lng = 72.423434;

    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    Point point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(lng,lat ));
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(point);
    System.out.println(json);
```

and the output is

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[72.423434,32.3456789]}
```

and i want output to be

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[32.3456789,72.423434]}
```

Comment: You can write your own serialiser for `Point` class. Default serialisation is: [GeometrySerializer](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometrySerializer.java). In custom serialiser you can specify order of elements in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tweak [GeometrySerializer](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometrySerializer.java), since the order is hardcoded in lines [174-175](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/df56dc9b3de8620024879bb979a2da3ec48c07b7/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometrySerializer.java#L174-L175).

In order to avoid writing a serializer by yourself, you could just copy `GeometrySerializer` and invert those two lines, but you would effectively not be using the official jts-data-type, and future modifications on the library would not be reflected in your copied serializer unless you do it manually.

Alternatively, just decorate the `GeometrySerializer` and use the `InverseCoordinateFilter` before calling it:

```java
public static class CustomGeometrySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Geometry> {
  private GeometrySerializer innerSerializer;
  private InvertCoordinateFilter inverter = new InvertCoordinateFilter();

  public CustomGeometrySerializer() {
    this(new GeometrySerializer());
  }

  public CustomGeometrySerializer(GeometrySerializer innerSerializer) {
    this.innerSerializer = innerSerializer;
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Geometry value, JsonGenerator jgen,
      SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

    // Create a new Geometry to avoid mutating the original one
    Geometry newValue = value.copy();
    newValue.apply(inverter);
    innerSerializer.serialize(newValue, jgen, provider);
  }

  private static class InvertCoordinateFilter implements CoordinateFilter {
    public void filter(Coordinate coord) {
      double oldX = coord.x;
      coord.x = coord.y;
      coord.y = oldX;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, instead of registering `JtsModule`, create a module yourself with your deserializer:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule inverseJtsModule = new SimpleModule();
inverseJtsModule.addSerializer(Geometry.class, new CustomGeometrySerializer());
mapper.registerModule(inverseJtsModule);

double lat  = 32.3456789;
double lng = 72.423434;

GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
Point point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(lng, lat));
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(point);
System.out.println(json);
```

You can now safely serialize your geometries without explicitly inverting each one. For deserialization, you can use the same approach, decorating [GeometryDeserializer](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometryDeserializer.java).